# Ruby array from two ranges

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array, range

I was looking for a way to create an array like:

```
[[1,1], [1,2], [1,3]
[2,1], [2,2], [2,3]
[3,1], [3,2], [3,3]]
```

For now I came up with this solution:

```
w=3 # or any int
h=3 # or any int
array = []
iw=1
while iw<=w do
  ih=1
  while ih <=h do
    array<<[iw, ih]
    ih+=1
  end#do
  iw+=1
end#do
```

But, I'm sure there must be a quicker way..?
This takes 1.107 seconds... (w=1900; h=1080)
Regards

EDIT:
I should've noticed that I'm stuck with 1.8.6..

Comment: There is no way this exact code takes over a second. You must have benchmarked it wrong!

Comment: Sorry, was with w=1900; h=1080

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is similar to @nicooga's answer, but I would use a range instead of manually creating the array (ie so you do not have to type each number for larger arrays).

```
range = (1..3).to_a
range.product(range)
#=> [[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3]]
```

Answer (score 6):

Use either [`product`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-product) or [`repeated_permutation`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-repeated_permutation):

```
[1, 2, 3].product([1, 2, 3]) # => [[1, 1], ...
# or
[1, 2, 3].repeated_permutation(2) # => [[1, 1], ...
```

`product` is in Ruby 1.8.7+ (accepts a block in 1.9.2+) while `repeated_permutation` in 1.9.2+. For other versions of Ruby, you can use include my [`backports`](https://github.com/marcandre/backports) gem and `include 'backports/1.9.2/array/repeated_permutation'` or `include 'backports/1.8.7/array/product'`.

Comment: @user1130886 Then definitely checkout `backports`. You'll be at basically at the level of 1.8.7 with a lot of goodies of 1.9, and in a few weeks I'm enabling some features of 2.0 too

Answer (score 3):

There is a faster way:

```
> [1,2,3].product([1,2,3])
=> [[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3]]
```